# Adding another statement to WHERE clause in SQLite query causes freeze. Why?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have these 2 queries:

```
SELECT d.C_ContactID, d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, d.C_DateCreated 
FROM duplicates as d 
WHERE d.C_DateCreated !=(select max(d2.C_DateCreated) 
FROM duplicates d2 
WHERE d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId)
```

and

```
SELECT d.C_ContactID, d.C_EmailAddress, d.C_DataSourceID, d.C_DateCreated 
FROM duplicates as d 
WHERE d.C_DateCreated !=(select max(d2.C_DateCreated) 
FROM duplicates d2 
WHERE d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId and d2.C_DataSourceId != '')
```

First returns much more records that second one but takes just 20 seconds and the second just freezes my browser...

Do you know why? I have indexed C_DataSourceId and C_DataSourceId.
This is my indexing:

```
create index duplicates_DataSourceId_DateCreated on duplicates(C_DataSourceId,  
C_DateCreated)
```

Result of first query are all the records, but one(the newest one), which are duplicates (according to  `C_DataSourceId`)

[image: IMG]

Comment: can u post an explain plan? So we can see the full-scans and index-scans

Comment: Also can you please tell us the result for below in where clase:
WHERE d2.C_DataSourceId != '' and d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId)

Comment: What is explain plan, I would like to post.

Comment: Explain plan is what describe how the query is fetching the result.
You can get the same by using below statement:
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <sql statement>

Comment: Instead of `d2.C_DataSourceId != ''` try like `d2.C_DataSourceId is not null`

Comment: I tried also is not null also not null also notnull .. always freeze and nothing returned.

Comment: I have also tried to add brackets etc.

Comment: Have you tried keeping the != "" check before as i have mentioned in my first comment ?

Comment: Exactly, I tried that as well.

Comment: One last thing to check: 
WHERE d.C_DataSourceId != '' and d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId)

Comment: You know what I found out? I tried that with just 10 000 records and it is working. But with 300 000 it freezes. I get it that maybe it needs more time but why is it much much much slower than the first query? And why is it that slow if it is indexed?

Comment: Can you get the explain plan in that case. Check if its filtering out the results first with d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId or d.C_DataSourceId != ''. Surely my guess is that its checking first d.C_DataSourceId != '' as d2.C_DataSourceId = d.C_DataSourceId is not going into long running. 
Mostly SO need to be applied in that case.

Comment: I am going to edit question by adding the query plan.

Comment: Copy the output as text into the question; and it would be useful to have the plan of both queries.

Comment: Output of the select query? It is 300 000 records.